# CPTGraphHostingView in a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, core-plot

I was really impressed, and really grateful about the answers I recived last time I asked here.

I have this problem with Core Plot.
I want to have a CPTGraphHostingView inside my UIView so I can have things like labels and scroll views below it.

I am using XCode 3.2 by the way.

How do I do this programmatically? Or with the Interface builder if possible.(I need the instructions to be detailed as im I bit new to this sort of thing)
Thanks for your support.

Comment: Can't you just add a new custom UIView with CPTGraphHostingView as its class within your existing UIView in Interface Builder?

Comment: You would think so... But unforunitely no.I come across loads of errors and the app just crashes, so I was wondering if doing progromaticly would make a difference. Probably not though. I would post the error through past bin if you think you can figure it out...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add a core plot graph to a UIView you have to add a CPTGraphHostingView as a subview to the UIView. In the example below, hostingView is a UIView and graphObject is a CPTXYGraph.

```
CPTGraphHostingView *graphHostingView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:hostingView.bounds];

[hostingView addSubview:graphHostingView];

graphHostingView.hostedGraph = graphObject;
```

Comment: `let graphHostingView = CPTGraphHostingView(frame: hostingView.bounds)` 
`hostingView.addSubview(graphHostingView)` 
`graphHostingView.hostedGraph = graphObject` in Swift

Answer (score 0):

Simple adding CPTGraphHostingView as a subView of UIView [programatically] didn't work for me.

I have searched through many threads and at the end I tried the simplest way to do this - I have created new UIView in interface builder and in this view I have created another UIView and change it to CPTGraphHostingView. Now I can simply create chart [like in tutorials] and link its main UIView anywhere I want.

I don't know why this didn't work programatically but it works from Interface Builder.

I use **Xcode 4.2** and **Core plot 1.0**